# mount error(5): Input/output error

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

first of all I’d like to note that the issue in question wasn’t one till my latest kernel update. Before I could mount every network share easily and quickly with a mount -a command.

I use only LTS kernels with my Manjaro Mate Distribution and it was my first attempt to upgrade it to a new kernel (4.9 to 4.14 LTS).

Can’t complain actually the update seems to be a success except for this **mount error(5): Input/output error** on my local network (that was working prior to this).

Since I’m not sure if this is KERNEL related (due to the update) or a CIFS or a SAMBA or a MOUNT or a FSTAB issue i’m posting here to get some community feedback.

my fstab line looks like this:

```
#Network Shares
//192.168.1.125/appdata /home/user/network/appdata cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials, uid=user 0 0
```

Hope I Can get some light on this…

Thanks in advance;

John

Comment: Is the `cifs-utils` package installed? Also, can you try adding `sec=ntlm` as the final parameter to your `/etc/fstab` entry?

Comment: Please add the output of `mount` to the question

Comment: is in the title:

`mount: /etc/fstab: erro de análise na linha 13 -- ignorado
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

The translation on that is analisys error on line13 - ignored
THe 13th line is in my original post btw

Comment: @maulinglawns yes it's installed, like I've told in the post it was working before i switched kernels

Comment: no one has nothing yet?

Answer (score 3):

I did a little digging in the internet and found a change in some samba/windows/cifs on this new kernel. Didn't understood all correctly but the tip works.

For anyone with the problem add `vers=1.0` in their fstab line. That did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

Had similar experience. Tried above and looked...well...everywhere.

The issue on my setup was a silly mistake.  I had not added the user access credentials to samba itself, i.e., as can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide

sudo  smbpasswd -a username

New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Added user username.

sudo smbpasswd -e username
Enabled user username.

Felt like a bozo when I finally got it working.

Comment: glad you made it :D